# Как программно создать GroupBox и добавить в него текст и кнопку?

Tags: c#, wpf

Мне нужно программно создать GroupBox и впихнуть в него также программно созданные Label и Button. При попытке добавить просто текст в лапках все норм, но когда пытаюсь добавить Label с помощью += вылазит ошибка "Оператор "+=" невозможно применить к операнду типа "object" и "Label".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка вылазит по делу.

Во-первых данный оператор служит для другого.
Во-вторых, чтобы добавить элементы в `GroupBox`, эти элементы, сначала, надо положить в какой-то контейнер. Например `StackPanel`.

```
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
Label lbl = new Label();
Button btn = new Button();
panel.Children.Add(lbl);
panel.Children.Add(btn);
panel.UpdateLayout();
```

А затем этот контейнер положить в контент `GroupBox`'а

```
myGroupBox.Content = panel
```